# Python - Extracting data between specific comment nodes with BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Looking to pick out specific data from a website such as prices, company info etc. Luckily, the website designer has put lots of tags such as

```
<!-- Begin Services Table -->
' desired data
<!-- End Services Table -->
```

What kind of code would I need in order for BS4 to return the strings between the given tags?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.100ll.com/searchresults.phpclear_previous=true&searchfor="+'KPLN'+"&submit.x=0&submit.y=0"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

text_list = soup.find(id="framediv").find_all(text=True)
start_index = text_list.index(' Begin Fuel Information Table ') + 1
end_index = text_list.index(' End Fuel Information Table ')
for item in text_list[start_index:end_index]:
    print(item)
```

Here's the website in question:

http://www.100ll.com/showfbo.php?HashID=cf5f18404c062da6fa11e3af41358873

Comment: Sorry about that @Barmar I forgot to post my original code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select the `table` element after those specific comment(s), then you can select all the comment nodes, filter them based on the desired text, and then select the the next sibling `table` element:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))

for comment in comments:
    if comment.strip() == 'Begin Services Table':
        table = comment.find_next_sibling('table')
        print(table)
```

Alternatively, if you want to get *all* data between those two comments, then you could find the first comment and then iterate over all the next siblings until you find the closing comment:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

data = []

for comment in soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
    if comment.strip() == 'Begin Services Table':
        next_node = comment.next_sibling

        while next_node and next_node.next_sibling:
            data.append(next_node)
            next_node = next_node.next_sibling

            if not next_node.name and next_node.strip() == 'End Services Table': break;

print(data)
```